Unable to link files with eachother in Django
I was working on something, and I'm stuck.
Here is what I'm trying to do - suppose a user enters the order number on the site (named index.html), I would like to check if that order exists in the database. If it does, then it should redirect the user to the shipment page (shipment.html), where all the details are available regarding the same. I'm completely blank and not getting any ideas whatsoever. Please help.
Edit - There are no errors when trying to run this, but nothing happens when a user enters their order number on the site. The website does nothing apart from reloading the page.
here is what I tried doing, still not working!
**Here are the source code -
index.html code of that section -
{% block content %}


          {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">
              Track
            </button>
        </form>
      {% endblock %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
          {% for message in messages %}
            <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

**views.py - **
def shipment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_number = request.POST['order_number']
        try:
            shipment = Shipment.objects.get(order_number=order_number)
            return redirect('shipment')
        except Shipment.DoesNotExist:
            message = f"Order ID {order_number} does not exist in the database."
    else:
        message = ""
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'message': message})


**models.py - **
class Shipment(models.Model):
    member_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tracking_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    current_location = models.CharField()
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    delivery_date = models.IntegerField()


**urls.py - **

urlpatterns = [path("", views.index, name="index"),
               path("", views.login, name="login"),
               path('', views.shipment, name='shipment'),
               path('index.html', views.index, name='index'),
               path('shipment', views.shipment, name='shipment'),]

I have provided all the necessary code that might help. I'm hoping someone will step forward and help me out.

What's happening? is there an error? is there a blank page? Do you have logs? You didn't explain what the error is.

There are no errors when trying to run this, but nothing happens when a user enters their order number on the site. The website does nothing apart from reloading the page.

Have you defined app_name in urls.py? Share complete urls.py and template settings.

@MalcolmInTheCenter

here is the GitHub link. Could you take a look?  link - https://github.com/17AnuragMishra/innTrack-

Where are you submitting the order_number field from the frontend? I dont see name="order_number".

yup, the HTML code I shared is for a section where users can input details and check availability.

Try:

Check form method is POST on index.html
(<form method="post">)
request.POST.get('order_number')


Nope, nothing is happening!
